# Getting Test Case Run time error

Tags: python

Im working on this question(not Homework)
Given a list of unsorted integers,A = {a1, a2, ...,an) can you find the pair of elements that have the smallest absolute difference between them? If there are multiple pairs, find them all.

This is what i came up with:

```
num = int(input())
array = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
diff = []
for i in range(len(array)):
    for j in array:
        diff.append(array[i]- j)

total = []
for i in diff:
    if i > 0:
        total.append(i)

grail = min(total)
holy = []
for i in range(len(array)):
     for j in array:
        if ((array[i] - j) == grail):
            holy.append(array[i]) 
            holy.append(j)

final = sorted(holy)
for item in final:
    print(item, end = ' ')
```

This runs for few cases but gets runtime error on large inputs,any suggestion i might try?

Ex:

```
Input = [-20 -3916237 -357920 -3620601 7374819 -7330761 30 6246457 -6461594 266854 -520 -470 ]

Output = -520 -470 -20 30
```

Explanation = (-470) - (-520) = 30 - (-20) = 50, which is the smallest difference.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did not bother to check your code for correctness because the implementation has complexity of O(n^2)

```
for i in range(len(array)):
 for j in array:
    if ((array[i] - j) == grail):
        holy.append(array[i]) 
        holy.append(j)
```

The required answer needs to have preferable complexity of O(log n). For achieving that you need to sort the list upfront.

```
from unittest import TestCase
import unittest
from sys import maxsize
from itertools import tee

def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return zip(a, b)



def solution(n):
    n = sorted(n)
    pairs = []
    diff = maxsize
    for l, u in pairwise(n):
        if u - l <= diff:
            diff = u - l
            pairs.append((diff, (l,u)))
    pairs = sorted(pairs)
    least = pairs[0][0]
    return list(map(lambda x: x[1], filter(lambda x: x[0] == least, pairs)))

class TestLeastDiffrence(TestCase):
    def testSimple(self):
        n = [-20, -3916237, -357920, -3620601, 7374819, -7330761, 30, 6246457, -6461594, 266854, -520, -470]
        self.assertEqual(solution(n),[(-520, -470), (-20, 30)])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your time,will check your code logic thoroughly.